How to install a 3rd OS with Ubuntu
I have a laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24 with GRUB 2.06.
I would like to install another Windows in order to have:
-Ubuntu
-windows 10
-windows 10
What is the right procedure in order to not lose/damage the GRUB loader?
Or it will be deleted/overwritten by Windows’boot loader and it needs to be reinstalled with a Ubuntu live version?
Thanks in advance

In general a mixed bag on Windozes in the boot area is like arranging for an eventual disaster.
Unless you have very specific needs within Windows,
I'd instead recommend using virtual machines for other OS:es you might wish to run,
all based off a Linux as VM-host.
Virtualbox is quite good, I believe there are a few other choices too.
Just been forced to install Win11 at work, not liking the minute differences much.

Unfortunately there is the need to have 2 separate Windows. Because I need to work on cloning a drive, flashing, etc, and Windows adds some specific data to the system that breaks other functionalities after the drive was flashed and manufacture SN, PID are changed.
If I use a virtual machine, the host OS would see the drive before and after the flash ing and some functionalities stop working - it adds some random numbers to the device instance path. In addtion the software ghostbuster doesn't help in cleaning the registry. Thus a separate OS is needed, that' why I posted my question

I use embedded devices based off VMware - maybe not in the same manner as you do though... A separate VM for each group of software; has had my machine be very stable for years.

yes yes, but still the main host os would stop working, because it would add random numbers before the SN of the device instance id. The same OS cannot see cloned devices.
